# how to check whether association exists rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables

1. Post
2. Category

I have the following code in my controller:

```
@category = Category.find(id)
```

Suppose consider category as `mobile, car, bike`

I need to check the existence of mobile or car or bike. So that I can disable the input element.  I tried:

```
<% @category.each do |cat| %>
    <% if cat.posts.exists %>
        class = 'active'
    <% else %>
        class = 'inactive'
    <% end %>
    <div class="#{class}"><%= cat.name %></div>

<% end %>
```

The above code always runs the else condition.

Following are the categories:

1. Mobile
2. Car
3. Bike

If in my post table with column `category_id has the field with value 1` then `mobile should have a class active` and the other two should be inactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `any?` method:

```
<% @category.each do |cat| %>
  <div class="#{cat.posts.any? ? 'active' : 'inactive'}"><%= cat.name %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Now also running only else part

Comment: @user2749548 Could you post your `Post` and `Category` models in your question?

Comment: @user2749548 My answer should work. Try using the rails console to see if you have any categories that have associated models. Also could you post the controller code for the action you are accessing?